# Load a worksheet with openpyxl and ignore other worksheet which contains pivot table

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl, xlsx

I have an .xlsx file which contains 2 worksheets. The first one contains regular data (nothing fancy), while the second one contains pivot tables. I need only the data form the first worksheet and I want to ignore the second one, but the pivot tables raise error: `TypeError: expected <type 'basestring'>` when `openpyxl.load_workbook` is called.

The error is raised in: `openpyxl/reader/excel.py`, in line:    `pivot_caches = parser.pivot_caches`.

I tried with `openpyxl` versions `2.6.4` and `2.5.1`. I'm using Python 2.7.

After deleting the 2nd worksheet, the error is gone and the data from the 1sth worksheet is read correctly. However, these files are uploaded by users and although I don't need the pivot tables, I would like to avoid forcing users to remove the unnecessary worksheet(s), if possible.

Sample code:

```
from io import BytesIO

import openpyxl

pivot = '~/Downloads/file_with_pivot_tables.xlsx'

with open(pivot) as fin:
    content = BytesIO(fin.read())
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(content)  # this line fails
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Entire error trace:

```
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 224, in load_workbook
    pivot_caches = parser.pivot_caches
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/packaging/workbook.py", line 125, in pivot_caches
    cache = get_rel(self.archive, self.rels, id=c.id, cls=CacheDefinition)
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/packaging/relationship.py", line 162, in get_rel
    obj.deps = get_dependents(archive, rels_path)
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/packaging/relationship.py", line 130, in get_dependents
    rels = RelationshipList.from_tree(node)
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 84, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/packaging/relationship.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.Target = Target
  File "/Users/gi/lib/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 44, in __set__
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
TypeError: expected <type 'basestring'>
```

Comment: I've never used BytesIO so I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it. I think that  ```content``` is not a readable file path for ```load_workbook``` so that's probably generating the error. Why don't you just reference the file path directly?

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Why are you using `BytesIO` ?

Comment: @AMC I added error stacktrace. I use BytesIO because I can't read directly from file, because of the environment I work on - GCP.

Comment: @giliev Oh, so that's not what the code actually looks like?

Comment: yes, but the error is same, i.e. it is reproducible with the code I provided here

Comment: You can use read-only mode and you can also disable reading the caches with `keep_links=False`

Comment: @CharlieClark: Do you have any reference that setting keep_links=False will disable reading pivot caches?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the sheet that you want to manipulate:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('H:\\myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet1']
ws['E1'] = 'The sky is gray.'
wb.save('H:\\myfile.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

You can also get a list of all the sheet names if you need to check them first:

```
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

Comment: @giliev Without seeing your code it's difficult to determine what's causing the error. If you edit your post with the code I might be able to help.

Comment: I added code snippet. Will try to provide a file, but need to create new pivot table, to avoid revealing real information.

Comment: it is the `openpyxl.load_workbook()` method that throws the error - as already mentioned.